# How to post the content of a file to php using ajax prototype.js?

Tags: ajax

I am using ajax **prototype.js**. I have a input `type="file" id="fileId"` button.

`var fileName = $("fileId").value` gives the file name and not its contents.

How can I post the content of a file (selected from input `type="file"`) to php script using **Ajax.Updater** or **Ajax.Request**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do file uploads using AJAX like that. It's a browser security feature.

However, you can use an iframe to simulate this behavior.

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

This is *not* a file upload using AJAX, but it simulates the behavior.